# How can i add several copies of one form and submit them with different data? Flask, WTForms

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

Hellow. I have a document database and flask app that gives me web-based opportunity to see the db's docs, add them and delete. Every doc has only it's number and name.

Usually I add the documents one by one, cause i have the **WTForm** -

`class addDocForm(FlaskForm):
    doc_name = StringField('Название документа', validators=[DataRequired()])
    doc_number = StringField('Исходящий номер', validators=[DataRequired()])`

the **.html code** -

```
<form action="" method="post" >
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    <div class="row">
        <label>{{ form.doc_name.label }}</label>
        {{ form.doc_name(size=32) }}
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <label>{{ form.doc_number.label }}</label>
        {{ form.doc_number(size=32) }}
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <button type="submit">Добавить</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

and some **/route logic** -

```
@app.route('/add_doc', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def add_doc():
    form = addDocForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        doc = Doc(doc_name=form.doc_name)
        if Doc.query.filter_by(doc_name=form.doc_name.data).first() == None:
            db.session.add(doc)
            db.session.commit()
```

So I add each document one by one filling this form and submitting it again and again. Now i've been tired. I want to save my energy by reducing number of clicking on submit button. Of course it's a joke, but the question is really about thing like this:

*how can i add several copies of this 'addDocForm' on one page, fill the fields of these copies and click submit only once?*

Is there any clever way to do that? I want to add for example 5-7 docs at once without the necessity to add them one by one. Let's suppose i've load the page with my form (one form) fill the fields, and than clicked '+' button and there appear another form.. fill the fields-> '+' button .. again. After all click the 'submit' button and all the data from filled fields by turns go to the data base. Is it real? any ideas? p.s. i have an idea on how to make it using clear sql + html + js, without flask-wtforms, sqalchemy and so on.. but i guess this is wrong way cause half of my app is already written using them. ) so many text, don't sure if anyone reach this point.. but still - help me, pls (((((

Comment: Can't you create a single form with 7 sets of fields, and then when you handle the submission ignore those that are empty?

Comment: since you don't actually use `doc_number`, drop it and since `doc_name` is a StringField just allow a separator token e.g. `,` and use `str.split(',')` to get a list of different `doc_names` and loop through and add each of them. This way your route automatically recognises multiple document name inputs in a single string field

Comment: I actually use doc_number, just mistake in the example. Your idea sounds good, thx. But what about using several StringFields and then unification their data to one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could construct a `MegaForm` using [field enclosures](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/fields.html#field-enclosures).

For example (untested):

```
from wtforms import StringField, FormField, FieldList

class AddDocForm(FlaskForm):
    doc_name = StringField('Название документа', validators=[DataRequired()])
    doc_number = StringField('Исходящий номер', validators=[DataRequired()])

class MegaForm(FlaskForm):
    documents = FieldList(FormField(AddDocForm), min_entries=7, max_entries=7)


@app.route('/add_doc', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def add_doc():
    form = AddDocForm() 

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        for idx, data in enumerate(form.documents.data):
            doc = Doc(doc_name=data["doc_name"])
            if Doc.query.filter_by(doc_name=data["doc_name"]).first() == None:
                db.session.add(doc)
                db.session.commit()
```

Comment: that is exactly i'm interested in. Thx! p.s. i've tried to search through the docs, but didn't managed to find something like that :( Thanks again!